# Getting undefined for the length of the dynamic array

Tags: solidity, addresses, testing

I'm getting `undefined` for the length of `multiSig` dynimic array, or `votes` in testing, no matter how many items are pushed into the array.

**FlightSuretyData.sol**

```
   address[] multiSig = new address[](0);
   function getMultiSigLength() public view returns (uint256) {
        return multiSig.length;
    }
```

**FlightSuretyApp.sol**

```
    function testGettingMultiSigLength() public view returns (uint256) {
        return flightSuretyData.getMultiSigLength();
    }
```

**test/flightSurety.js**

```
  it("test getting the length from getMultiSigLength()", async () => {
    // ARRANGE
    let votes;
    // ACT
    try {
      votes = await config.flightSuretyApp.testGettingMultiSigLength();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("votes error", e);
    }
    console.log(votes);
  });
```

When I log the `e.message` I get the following:

> hijackedStack: 'Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing
>   transaction: revert\n'

When I bring the array and the function to be combined within the same

**contract `FlightSuretyApp.sol`**

```
   address[] multiSig = new address[](0);
   function getMultiSigLength() public view returns (uint256) {
        return multiSig.length;
    }
    function testGettingMultiSigLength() public view returns (uint256) {
        return getMultiSigLength();
    }
```

it works fine which means something about reaching over to another contract that's causing the issue. I've had to import the the contract through `import "./FlightSuretyData.sol";`

**testConfig.js**

```js
var FlightSuretyApp = artifacts.require("FlightSuretyApp");
var FlightSuretyData = artifacts.require("FlightSuretyData");
var BigNumber = require("bignumber.js");

var Config = async function (accounts) {
  let owner = accounts[0];
  let firstAirline = accounts[1];

  let flightSuretyData = await FlightSuretyData.new();
  let flightSuretyApp = await FlightSuretyApp.new();

  return {
    owner: owner,
    firstAirline: firstAirline,
    weiMultiple: new BigNumber(10).pow(18),
    testAddresses: testAddresses,
    flightSuretyData: flightSuretyData,
    flightSuretyApp: flightSuretyApp,
  };
};

module.exports = {
  Config: Config,
};
```

And this is how I authorized `FlightSuretyApp` to `FlightSuretyData`

```js
  before("setup contract", async () => {
    config = await Test.Config(accounts);
    await config.flightSuretyData.authorizeCaller(
      config.flightSuretyApp.address
    );
  });
```

Comment: Change `catch (e) {}` to `catch (e) {console.log(e.message);}`, and you'll know why.

Comment: @goodvibration updated the question

Comment: What's so hard about doing `console.log(e.message)` instead of `console.log(e)`???

Comment: do you not see the `message` up there?  `Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

Comment: Yes, but me (and anyone else here) would have seen it much more clearly if you followed that instruction. And when you dump a huge non-relevant piece of text into your question, most people (me included) will not bother to read through and help you out.

Comment: but `e` necessarily includes `e.message`. I don't see the point of asking for `e.message` twice if `e` is already there

Comment: You've just fixed your question according to that, so I think you actually do see the point!

Comment: And without even seeing your code (which you **should** have posted here), your problem is obviously the fact that in contract `FlightSuretyApp`, variable `flightSuretyData` is not pointing to the address of a `FlightSuretyData` instance (I would guess that you've left it as `address(0)`, and it is therefore not pointing to anything).

Comment: How do you have a variable point to the address of a certain contract? Currently, I've tried `import "./FlightSuretyData.sol";` and initializing it with `FlightSuretyData flightSuretyData;`  I've also tried having an abstract contract instead of porting `abstract contract FlightSuretyData {
    function getMultiSigLength() external virtual returns (uint256);`. None works

Comment: `FlightSuretyData flightSuretyData` is not an initialization, it's a declaration!

Comment: You need to set `flightSuretyData = something` at some point in your code before you try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In contract `FlightSuretyApp`, you should set variable `flightSuretyData` to the address of a `FlightSuretyData` instance.

Here are a few ways to do it (depending on your use-case):

```
    constructor(FlightSuretyData _flightSuretyData) public {
        flightSuretyData = _flightSuretyData;
    }

    constructor(arg1, arg2, ...) public {
        flightSuretyData = new FlightSuretyData(arg1, arg2, ...);
    }

    function setFlightSuretyData(FlightSuretyData _flightSuretyData) public {
        flightSuretyData = _flightSuretyData;
    }

    function setFlightSuretyData(arg1, arg2, ...) public {
        flightSuretyData = new FlightSuretyData(arg1, arg2, ...);
    }
```